# How to read a file as Array Buffer in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have been trying to send a file to my websocket as an Array Buffer. I have accomplished to have done the following:

```
var bytes = await imageFile.readAsBytes();
var buffer = bytes.buffer;
var m = base64.encode(Uint8List.view(buffer));
```

But this returns as a byte buffer string but I need it as Array Buffer like the image shown below:

[image]

How can i accomplish to send my file data as the data shown in the image? I tried importing dart.html and tried using filereader.readasArrayBuffer, but it does not work with flutter mobile app and i get an error during compile. Is it possible to send data like the image above. If yes, any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just need my image file to be converted to this format:
<Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 00 e1 00 00 00 e1 08 03 00 00 00 09 6d 22 48 00 
00 01 32 50 4c 54 45 4f 92 ff ff ff ff f9 d2 a0 ... 4906 more bytes>

Instead i could only achieve the following format
[137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,68,82,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,8,6,0,0,0,244,120,212,250,0,0,0,...

My websocket is only accepting BufferArray. I know flutter has no such class but dart.html has a filereader which has a function reader.readAsArrayBuffer

Comment: This is from my NodeJs Socket. The socket is used to chat and send files in real time. I need to send data to the socket like the image shown in the question. The problem I am facing is I am not being able to send my file data as the image shown above. I can only send bytes from my flutter application. What can i do to solve this problem? I hope its clear to you now.

Comment: it is just a string message that the user writes in chat. It is used to send messages to the appropriate user.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Uint8List Class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-typed_data/Uint8List-class.html)

### If you want to send a proper post/get request

Follow [this documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/send-data), especially

> This recipe covers how to create an Album by sending an album title to the JSONPlaceholder using the http.post() method.

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<MyImage> createMyImage(String message, String fileName, Uint8List fileData) async {
  const String ENDPOINT = 'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/'; // replace with your endpoint
  final response = await http.post(
    Uri.https(ENDPOINT, 'images'), // images is the additional path to your endpoint, optional
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
    body: json.encode(<String, dynamic>{ // use dynamic keyword instead of String if your json as a tree, note that I use json.encode here
      'message': message,
      'file': {'name': fileName, 'data': fileData}
    }),
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 201) {
    return MyImage.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to create image.');
  }
}

class MyImage {
  final String message;
  final String fileName;
  final Uint8List fileData;

  MyImage({this.message, this.fileName, this.fileData});

  factory MyImage.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return MyImage(
      message: json['message'],
      fileName: json['file']['name'],
      fileData: json['file']['data'],
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() {
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _controllerFileName = TextEditingController();
  Future<MyImage> _futureMyImage;
  Uint8List data;

  /* have your data to be equal to your images bytes:
  var bytes = await imageFile.readAsBytes();
  data = bytes.buffer;
  */

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Create Data Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Create Data Example'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: (_futureMyImage == null)
              ? Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                controller: _controller,
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter Title'),
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: _controllerFileName,
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter Title'),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                child: Text('Create Data'),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _futureMyImage = createMyImage(_controller.text, _controllerFileName.text, data);
                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
          )
              : FutureBuilder<MyImage>(
            future: _futureMyImage,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text(snapshot.data.message);
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text("${snapshot.error}");
              }

              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I think what is missing in the documentation is that you need to use [dynamic type when a json type is not a string but list of (list of list of) string](https://dart.dev/guides/language/type-system).

> A dynamic list is good when you want to have a list with different kinds of things in it.

---

### If you are just looking to format the output

```dart
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:core';

Uint8List bytes = imageFile.readAsBytesSync();
String hexa = toHex(bytes);
String s = "<Buffer " + (hexa.length > 30 ? hexa.substring(0, 30) : hexa) + ((bytes.elementSizeInBytes - 10) > 0 ? "... ${bytes.elementSizeInBytes - 10} more bytes>" : ">");
print(s);
```

And the function to convert:

```dart
String toHex(Uint8List s) {
  String res = "";
  for(int i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
    res += s[i].toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0') + " ";
  return res;
}
```

If you need to send the full values, and its not just about display, use:

```dart
String s = "<Buffer $hexa>";
```

NB: hexa will have an extra space that you can remove easily

Comment: Hello, i tried the above code but its giving me the following format:
[137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,68,82,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,8,6,0,0,0,244,120,212,250,0,0,0,...
But i need it like this <Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a ... more bytes>

Comment: Your edited answer is nearly same as before.

Comment: i GET

ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '+' was called on null.

Comment: see my edit it works now, forgot to initialize `res=""`

Comment: It works now the image is uploaded to server but the problem now is that the image file can not be opened as proper file data is not sent. It is sending data like this when i print the string:
<Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00

Comment: This does not help. A file is uploaded to my database but the data sent is garbage value. The file does not open as the bytes sent from client side is wrong sadly.

Comment: If you want the right data to be sent you just need to send your Uint8List `Uint8List bytes = imageFile.readAsBytesSync();`

Comment: I did whatever you suggested in the answer. The result is the same. When i try to open the uploaded file using POSTMAN, i just get the buffer data i sent. It means the image file cannot be opened as it contains error.

Comment: if you send the data as bytes it will be working, what you see is the decimal representation of its binary numbers, 137 in base 10 = 89 in base 16, I thought you only needed to format the output string, see my edit

Comment: toHex method helped me to find my solution thanks